# How can I get focused form element by using JS?

Tags: javascript, forms, focus, keycode, onfocus

For example

```
<form>
    <div class="form-control">
       <input type="text" name="username">
    </div>
    <div class="form-control">
       <input type="text" name="password">
    </div>
</form>
```

when I press tab key when cursor is in input which name is **username**, How can I get the new focused element that name is **password** with using JS

When I get the element with this code;

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(evt) 
{

    if (evt.keyCode === 9) {
       console.log(document.activeElement);
    }

});
```

this returned the input-1 which name is **username**, but I want to get **password** input. How can I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your event listener is bound to `keydown`, which means it will trigger before the actual keypress is "complete" (down and then up), so the focus hasn't actually changed when the event handler executes. Change to `keyup` and the focus will change before your event handler.

```js
document.addEventListener('keyup', function(evt) 
{

    if (evt.keyCode === 9) {
       console.log(document.activeElement);
    }

});
```

```html
<form>
    <div class="form-control">
       <input type="text" name="username">
    </div>
    <div class="form-control">
       <input type="text" name="password">
    </div>
</form>
```